# Почему req.isAuthenticated() return false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Я имею сайт на ноде с использованием passportjs и express c бд postgresql. 
У меня есть middleware для сессий пользователя

```
var session = require('express-session');
var config = require('config');

module.exports = session({
    secret: config.secret,
    resave: true, 
    saveUninitialized: true, 
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly : true,
        maxAge : 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 //30days
    }
});
```

И также проверка авторизован ли пользователь

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('----------------' + req.isAuthenticated()) // true
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
        return next();
    } else {
        res.render('permissionDenied', {title: 'Permission denied'});
    }
};
```

Все хорошо. Авторизация работает. сессии тоже. Но когда я захотела использовать store для сессий

```
var pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
module.exports = session({
    store: new pgSession({
        conString : config.databaseString
    }),
    secret: 'SECRET',
    resave: true, //don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: true, // create session until something stored
    expires: date.toUTCString(),
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly : true,
        maxAge : 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 //30days
    }
});
```

`isAuthenticated()` всегда возвращает false

скажите в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: В [примере](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple#usage) в `store: new pgSession` указано большее количество аргументов. Попробуйте по аналогии. Если поможет - отпишитесь, оформлю как ответ, чтобы вопрос закрыть и чтобы другим помогло)

Comment: я переделала на store Redis - что мне и помогло

Comment: тоже хороший вариант)